# Adding Parent Link Automatically When Bug is Created

Tags: azure-devops

The organization I am with has transitioned to Azure DevOps for source control and for Sprint Management.  I am responsible for investigating moving the organization to Azure DevOps for testing off of another solution.  There is one question I have received from multiple people after doing some demonstrations that I have not been able to get an answer on.

What I have been asked if the system can do, is that when a Bug is entered during a Test Execution, for it to automatically have the User Story that the script is related to be set as a parent.

For example:

If I have User Story 123, which has a Tested By relationship to Test Case Test1. Test Case Test1 is in Test Plan ABC, which was created with the Area Path of my team and Iteration of the current Iteration.  If I create a Bug while executing Test1 (in a Test Suite in Test Plan ABC), it currently adds the Bug to the current Iteration, but under an Unparented story.  We would like to see that bug automatically appear under User Story 123.

Is this possible?  Thanks for any information regarding this.

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the below answer could help you achieve what you want? If yes, you can accept the answer thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you still facing some issues, feel free to leave comment here :-)

Comment: Glad you have the solution. You can convert it to answer and accept it. It will help other community users who have the same error. You can refer to [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) about how to accept the answer. Thanks. : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for anyone else searching, I was able to resolve my issue.

What ended up being the solution was using the Create Test Suite from Requirement option, within a Test Plan.  This is a very useful method for our use, as once the Test Suite is setup, and Test Cases which are created with a Tested By/Test Relationship (User case should show Tested By in the Related Work section, the test case will show a Tests entry to the User story) will automatically be added into the Test Suite.  Then, when testing, when you create a new Bug from within a Test Execution, will automatically be created with the User Story as a Parent to the Bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Create work item task behind your test task in your build/release pipeline.

In this task, you can set the work item link type and target work item.
[image]

And other conditions about the work item.
[image]

You can set the Control Options as below.
[image]

It means, only when the test task has failed, this task will run.

Hops this will help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.  I checked into this and it didn't solve the problem, as the response appears to be in reference to automated testing and i was trying to solve for manual testing.